Untwisted spectrum of $\text{SU}_k(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ WZW model
I am interested in constructing the untwisted spectrum of $\text{SU}_k(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ Wess-Zumino-Witten model.
Representation theory of $SU(2)$
Labelling the basis of spin-$j$ representation space as $\{|j, m\rangle\}$ where $j\in \{0,\frac{1}{2}, 1,\frac{3}{2}, 2, \cdots \frac{k}{2}\}$ and $m\in \{-j, -j+1, \cdots, j\}$,
For spin-$j$ representation, the angular momentum operators $\{J_1, J_2, J_3\}$ are $(2j+1)\times (2j+1)$ dimensional matrices that form a Lie algebra that satisfies the following commutation relations:
$$[J_i, J_j] = i\epsilon_{ijk} J_k\tag{1}$$
where $i, j, k \in \{x, y, z\}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol. The raising and lowering operators $J_+$ and $J_-$ can then defined as:
$$J_+ = J_1 + i J_2 \quad  \quad J_- = J_1 - i J_2\tag{2}$$
Whose actions on basis states are given by
$$J_+|j, m\rangle = \sqrt{(j-m)(j+m+1)}|j, m+1\rangle\tag{3}$$
$$J_-|j, m\rangle = \sqrt{(j+m)(j-m+1)}|j, m-1\rangle\tag{4}$$
Since $J_z$ is diagonal, the action for $J_z$ becomes $J_z |j, m\rangle = m |j, m\rangle$. Furthermore, the fact that $J_+|j, j\rangle = 0$ identifies highest-weight states.
Indeed, any element $U\in \text{SU}(2)$ in spin-$j$ representation can be represented as $U = e^{iJ\cdot \hat{n}\theta}$ where identifying $\theta = 2\pi$ gives us the element $-\mathbb{I}_{2j+1}$. Then choosing $\vec{n}$ so that $\hat{n}\cdot J$ aligns with $z$-axis, half-integer spins transform under $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action as
$$-\mathbb{I}_{2j+1}|j, m\rangle = e^{
\pi i J\cdot \hat{n}} |j, m\rangle = e^{\pi i\pi m}|j, m\rangle = (-1)^{m} |j, m\rangle \tag{3}$$
Similarly for integer spins
$$-\mathbb{I}_{2j+1}|j, m\rangle = e^{
2\pi i J\cdot \hat{n}} |j, m\rangle = e^{2\pi i\pi m}|j, m\rangle = (-1)^{2m} |j, m\rangle \tag{4}$$
For states to remain invariant under $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action, $-\mathbb{I}_{2j+1}|j, m\rangle = |j, m\rangle$, we require that $j$ be integer spin.
Construction of affine $\widehat{\mathfrak{su}}_k(2)$-representations
Given the finite-dimensional representation $V_j = \{|j, m\rangle | -j\leq m\leq j\}$, the loop module is formed as $\mathcal{H_j} = V_j\oplus \mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$ together with the canonical basis
$$
\left\{ |j, m\rangle \otimes t^n \mid m \in \{-j, -j+1, \ldots, j\}, \; n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
$$
For clarity, we can denote $
|j, m; n\rangle := |j, m\rangle \otimes t^n
$. Let's define the loop algebra action
$$
J_m^a \cdot |j, m'; l\rangle = (J^a\otimes t^m) \cdot |j, m'; l\rangle  = (J^a |j, m'\rangle) \otimes t^{m+l} = \sum_{m''} (J^a)_{m'', m'} |j, m''; m + l\rangle\tag{5}$$
Where $\{J^{a}_m\}$ are generators of the loop algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)\otimes \mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$ and satisfy $$[J_m^a, J_n^b] = [J^a\otimes t^m, J^b\otimes t^n] = [J^a, J^b]\otimes t^{m+n} = i \epsilon^{abc} J_{m+n}^c\tag{6}$$
We can finally construct the affine Lie algebra at the level $k$ as a central extension of the loop algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2) \otimes \mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]$
$$\widehat{\mathfrak{su}_k(2)} = \left(\mathfrak{su}(2)\otimes \mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}]\right)\oplus\mathbb{C}K\oplus\mathbb{C}L_0$$
The affine commutation relation becomes
$$[J_m^a + zK, J_n^b+wK] = i \epsilon^{abc} J_{m+n}^c +  \langle J^{a} | J^{b}\rangle m\delta_{m+n,0} K\tag{7}$$
$$[K, \widehat{\mathfrak{su}_k(2)}] = 0\quad [L_0, J^{a}_n] = -nJ^{a}_n\quad [L_0, L_0] = 0\tag{8}$$
Where $\langle\cdot |\cdot\rangle$ denotes Killing form on $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. For a compact Lie algebra like $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ for which Killing form is negative-definite, $\langle J^{a} | J^{b}\rangle = -\lambda \delta_{ab}$ for some scalar $\lambda$. To determine this, we'll make use of Casimir operator $J^2 = \sum^3_{a = 1}(J^a)^2$ whose eigenvalues are $j(j+1)$. Using the following definition
$$\langle J^{a} | J^{b}\rangle = 4\text{Tr}(J^{a}J^{b})\tag{9}$$
Let's try to obtain the Casimir
$$\begin{align}4\sum^3_{a = 1}\text{Tr}((J^{a})^2) = 4\text{Tr}\biggr(\sum^3_{a = 1}(J^a)^2\biggr) &= 4\text{Tr}(j(j+1)\mathbb{I}_{2j+1})\\&= 4j(j+1)(2j+1)\end{align}\tag{10}$$
Solving $-3\lambda = 4j(j+1)(2j+1)$ gives us $\lambda = -\frac{4j(j+1)(2j+1)}{3}$.
The vacuum representation of level $k$ is described as a highest-weight $\widehat{\mathfrak{su}}_{k}(2)$-module
$$\mathcal{V}_k(\mathfrak{su}(2)) = \left\{ \cdots (J_{-2}^3)^{n_2^3} (J_{+2}^3)^{n_2^+} (J_{-1})^{n_1^-} (J_{-1}^3)^{n_1^3} (J_{+1})^{n_1^+} (J_0^-)^{n_0^-} \, | j, j\rangle \, \middle| \, n_i^+, n_i^-, n_i^3 \geq 0 \right\}\cup \{|j, j\rangle\}\tag{11}$$
Together with the $\widehat{\mathfrak{su}}_{k}(2)$-action $$K|j,j\rangle = k|j,j\rangle,\space J^{a}_{n}|j,j\rangle = 0\space (n\geq 0), J^3_0|j,j\rangle = j|j,j\rangle\tag{12}$$
To compute the conformal dimension $\Delta$, we'll look at the eigenvalue of Virasoro mode under Sugawara construction
$$\begin{align}L_0 |j, j\rangle = \frac{1}{2(k + h^{\vee})} \left( \sum_{n \leq -1} J^a_{-n} J^a_n + \sum_{n \geq 0} J^a_{-n} J^a_n \right) |j, j \rangle &= \frac{1}{2(k + h^{\vee})} J^a_0 J^a_0 |j, j \rangle \\ &= \underbrace{\frac{j(j+1)}{2(k + h^{\vee})}}_{ = \Delta} |j, j \rangle\end{align}\tag{13}$$
Before proceeding further, can I hear your feedback as to whether this is reasonable?

This seems about right. Usually one further constraints the Hilbert space by reduction to the Borel subgroup. Then one constructs the BRST cohomolgy and recognizes that it is concentrated in the zeroth cohomology.

@Simp Thanks for your feedback. Let's say we defined the action of $\widehat{\mathfrak{su}_2(k)}$ on the representation $V_j$. Does this finally give us the untwisted spectrum? From what I understand, we are looking for highest-weight representations, orresponding to primary fields of the theory.

Yes you are looking for the integrable highest weight modules.
